# Unable to attach file in WithAttachment in Xam.Plugins.Messaging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

please review my code as I am not able to attach any file in EmailMessageBuilder.
Also I need to understand about the ContentType, what should I pass in ContentType?

```
FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
String Path = CrossGetLocalFilePath.Current.GetLocalPath(filedata.FileName);
var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
{
var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
.To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
.Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
.Body("Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin")
.WithAttachment(Path, "image/jpeg")
.Build();
emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
}
```

I am using above code in Xamarin.forms (Portable), my attachment could be an image, video or any file.

Getting error:

> Failed to attach file due to IO error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the path if we are using the below plugin for the Media Capture and Select image from the Gallery.

```
Xam.Plugin.Media
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the CrossFilePicker plugin and CrossGetLocalFilePath plugin before but I find the source code here:

CrossFilePicker : https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/tree/master/FilePicker/FilePicker

CrossGetLocalFilePath:https://github.com/bradyjoslin/GetLocalFilePathPlugin/blob/master/GetLocalFilePath/GetLocalFilePath.Plugin.Android/GetLocalFilePathImplementation.cs

This is the FileData object you got when you call CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

```
  namespace Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions
    {
        public class FileData
        {
            public byte[] DataArray { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

DataArray is your file data, and FileName is your file name. It does not contain the file path.

And you call the another plugin CrossGetLocalFilePath to get the file path according to the file name.
in the CrossGetLocalFilePath source code it just implements in Android platform:

```
public class GetLocalFilePathImplementation : IGetLocalFilePath   
    {    
        public string GetLocalPath(string fileName)    
        {    
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);    
            return System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);  
        }   
    }
```

it not return the file path you want. It returned system special file path.

So in your case it is not possible to get the file path by these plugins.

But I recommend you to overwrite the CrossFilePicker plugin.

Take UWP as an example：

```
public class FilePickerImplementation : IFilePicker
    {

        public async Task<FileData> PickFile()
        {
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
                Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                var array = await ReadFile(file);
                return new FileData
                {
                    DataArray = array,
                    FileName = file.Name
                    FilePath = file.Path;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This is the implementation of file picker in UWP. You can add the FilePath property in the FileData Object as the code shows before.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and again. but I am getting an error in above code, I can't get the reference of `IFilePicker`, am I dump?

Comment: I extremely apologize for the above stupid question, I have implemented the separate class with the reference of the `IFilePicker` now I am getting the error in `Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker()` do I have to write this code in each platform? I am working on Xamarin.forms (portable)

Comment: Yes you need to  write this code in each platform. Just like develop an xamarin plugin..

"IFilePicker" is the source code of the plugin, not from Xamarin(portable) or .net .  You need to defined by yourself.                 Check the source code of the plugin: https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/tree/master/FilePicker/FilePicker  you will understand what happened.

Comment: And you just need to add `FilePath` property to `FileData` object in the plugin.

Comment: I got the solution, Thank You sooooooooo much for your help. However, I can't rate your answer, as I don't have 15 reputations.

Comment: You are welcome, you can mark the answer as a solution I think.

Comment: I can't, it's giving me an error, you require 15 reputations to mark this answer. If you can upvote my question then I will be really gladful. :)

[another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762069/how-to-play-rtmp-server-address-in-xamarin-forms-shared)