# How to play RTMP server address in Xamarin.forms (Shared)

Tags: c#, xamarin, video-streaming, xamarin.forms, rtmp

I want to play RTMP server address in Xamarin.forms (Shared), as I am a beginner and don't know much about the Xamarin.Forms(Shared). So, can anybody help in this? How to play a video with RTMP server address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The temporary solutions is, I have to use the WebView.

Comment: Have you made any further progress with this or are you still using a webview?

Comment: I am still using the webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [LibVLCSharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) to play RTMP stream 
I am using by myself and works flawlessly easy. I had issues with [ExoPlayer bindings for xamarin](https://github.com/Baseflow/ExoPlayerXamarin) or [MediaManager for xamarin](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager)

Various Samples, which also includes xamarin.forms
https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples

For streaming you could use 
https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-Yasea

Comment: Do you have an example? I tried to do it but the screen is black. `videoStream.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libvlc);
            videoStream.MediaPlayer.Play(new Media(_libvlc, new Uri("rtmp://live.restream.io/live/xxxxxxxxxxxx")));`

Comment: Try running https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples MediaElement sample with original link and then use your. Also try first run rtmp from windows VLC player only then try android

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try as you mention. In vlc for windows put the rtmp link but it just keeps loading and does not show anything. Regards!

Comment: If you create repro github i could try be myself

Comment: ok, I'll create it tomorrow and I'll share it with you