# Unable to attach files via WithAttachment using EmailMessageBuilder in Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to send an email with attachment using `EmailMessageBuilder` in `Xamarin.Form (android and IOS)`.

No errors given, just:

> unable to attach file

when Sent email is pressed.

```
 private void Notification_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;

        if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
        {

            var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()

                                 .To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
                                 .Cc("cc.plugins@xamarin.com")
                                 .Bcc(new[]{ "bcc1.plugins@xamarin.com",
                       "bcc2.plugins@xamarin.com" })
                                            .Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
                                            .Body("Testing 123")
                                 .WithAttachment("<C:/Users/L30902/Desktop/hyphenApp(21-10-2018)/hyphenApp/hyphenApp/hyphenApp.Android/Resources/drawable/app_logo.png>", "image/png")
                                            .Build();




            emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is a Windows path, you would need an Android path

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734357/unable-to-attach-file-in-withattachment-in-xam-plugins-messaging

Comment: @SushiHangover hi, can i have some examples of android path?